# Is checking for isLoggedIn on client side unnecessary?

Tags: authentication, authorization

Do I have to check on all requests to server if user is logged in or it is enough if API returns 401 for request, which require aputontification?

Relying on API's 401 response code I may end up showing user status as logged in for some time until there will be a request allowed for authorised users only.

Which is the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle authentication is to check upon every request.

The overhead is negligible and if lazy authentication checks can lead to wrongly displayed authentication states, are definitely not in the slim area where speed outweighs security.